# downloading a base64 image using javascript not working on IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have a canvas with ID `image-download`, i am converting the canvas to a base64 image/png for download like this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("image-download");
var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
this.href = img;
this.download = name + '_qr.png';
```

This works on Firefox and chrome, it opens a `save as` window which you use to download an image.

But when i try it on IE9, it does not work. Any solutions are greatly appreciated!

Thanks!